# How to Convert Multiple Unix TimeStamp to Pandas Datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I get the following error when trying to convert multiple the unix timestamps to a datetime in pandas, I've tried setting values but seem to not be getting it right.

> ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month,
>   day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing

Here's the code:

```
pd.to_datetime(ksdata[['state_changed_at','created_at','launched_at']])
```

It's got to be something simple but I just can't see it.

**Sample of file**

[image]

Comment: Can you post ksdata.head()?

Comment: @Vaishali added a screenshot of the header couldn't find a more elegant way to do it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dataset helps as its easier to test the solution but anyway for unix timestamp, solution would be

```
ksdata[['state_changed_at','created_at','launched_at']] = ksdata[['state_changed_at','created_at','launched_at']].\
apply(pd.to_datetime, unit = 's')
```

As @MaxU suggested, if you need to convert all the columns ending with '_at' to timestamp, you can filter them using

```
ksdata.filter(regex='_at$')
```

Comment: we can try to filter columns ending with `_at` like this: `ksdata.filter(regex='_at$')`, if OP doesn't have other columns (not UNIX timestamps) ending with `_at`...

Comment: @MaxU, thanks! Let me will update the answer. Only thing is, we don't know how many columns are present in the dataframe and how do they look like.

Comment: @Vaishali thank you! I always forget about the apply function! I must try remember this :)

Comment: @MaxU thanks for highlighting that I can use filter, again something that I keep forgetting exists.